# AngularJS unit testing Karma - unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up unit tests on our legacy AngularJS app. I am using the standard karma along with angular-mock to set up the tests cases. But I am getting issues with `Unknown provider` when I am trying to inject some services and factory. My karma.conf looks something like this (I have removed a lot of stuff for brevity)

```
module.exports = function(config) {   config.set({

     basePath: '',

     // frameworks to use
     // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     frameworks: ['jasmine'],

     // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
     files: [
       './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
       "http://cf._____.com/content/myfootprints/js/priorityqueue.js",
       "http://cf._____.com/content/myfootprints/js/ng-flow-standalone.js",
       INCLUDED ALL THE DEPENDENCIES HERE 
       './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
       './static/js/app/main.js',
       './static/tests/**/*.js'
     ]
     preprocessors: {
       './static/js/app/**/main.js':['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
       './static/js/app/**/*.js':['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
     },
```

In our application we have a main.js that is importing all the controllers and factories into the application using `imports` and `requireDir`. It looks something like this

```
const requireDir = require('webpack-requiredir');

    import './isocurrency.js';
    import './myfp_uirouter.js';
    import './infobubble.js';
    // other imports
    requireDir(require.context('./controllers', true, /.*\.js$/))
    requireDir(require.context('./directives', true, /.*\.js$/))
    requireDir(require.context('./factories', true, /.*\.js$/))
    requireDir(require.context('./filters', true, /.*\.js$/))
```

I have a file with unit tests that looks something like this

```
describe('Unit test file, function(){
  var generalUtilFactory;
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
    generalUtilFactory = $injector.get('generalUtilsFactory'); <--- getting unknown provider 
    // Also tried to inject it in 
    //via function($rootScope,... _generalUtilFactory_)
  }));

Other code
  .
  .
  .
  .

});
```

Now I do have general util factory that is being imported through the main.js and is being registered in the app module. I checked to see it in debugger. It looks like this

```
angular.module('app').factory('generalUtilsFactory', ['$timeout', '$filter', 'FileSaver', 'Blob', function($timeout, $filter, FileSaver, Blob) {
    var generalUtilsFactory = {};

    generalUtilsFactory.getKeys = function(o){
```

I am not quite sure what is happening here. All the needed files have been included and all the es6 they have been properly converted. Some help in this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inject the main module before injecting the service. Maybe doing something like this will help:

```
describe('Service Tests', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    var _generalUtilsFactory;

    beforeEach(inject(function (generalUtilsFactory) {
        _generalUtilsFactory = generalUtilsFactory
    }));
});
```

Comment: Na that doesn't solve it. module(app) will just create a mock module right?

Comment: Yes, we want to make sure the main module is loaded before we inject the factory. The only thing that I can think of is the use of $injector. Can we try it without the $injector once just inject(function (generalUtilsFactory)?